# Converting CRS?

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, well-known-text

I am trying to convert an N-triple RDF file which has geometries with WKT which use EPSG/3857 and I need to convert all WKTs to EPSG/4326 (I think it is the same as WGS84).

As a first step, I tried using cs2cs for one point, but the result was not a pair of numbers:

`echo -75.137109 42.280707 | cs2cs +init=epsg:3857 +to +init=epsg:4326`

`0d0'2.43"W      0d0'1.367"N 0.000`

Does anyone have a pointer for the proper use of cs2cs tool or some other utility or even a java function that I could include in my project?

Comment: Are you sure your values aren't already in latitude-longitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `-f` flag to control the output format:

```
$ echo -75.137109 42.280707 | cs2cs -f %f +init=epsg:3857 +to +init=epsg:4326 
-0.000675   0.000380 0.000000
```

Note that (-75,42) in epsg:3857 is 75 metres west and 42 metres north of where the equator hits the Greenwich meridian. So the output in lat-long is very near 0. The default output was "DMS" - degrees, minutes, and seconds.

With `-f %f` you convert the DMS to fractional degrees.